# Constraints no se ajustan a diferentes pantallas

Tags: ios, xcode

Buenas, tengo un pequeño problema. En `StoryBoard` he diseñado la pantalla con la opción `Use Auto Layout` desactivando la opción `Use Size Classes` he añadido los constraints necesarios y en las pantallas de 5.5 se ve de maravilla todo ajustado, pero el problema viene en las pantallas de 4.7, 4 y 3.5 que no se ajusta nada bien. También intenté activando la opción `Use Size Classes` y no he obtenido ningún resultado.
[image: Storyboard no funciona bien]

Comment: ¿estás utilizando iOS 9?

Answer (score 1):

creo que lo que necesitas es esto:

[Emulando el aspecto](http://www.iteramos.com/pregunta/10804/emulando-el-aspecto-ajuste-comportamiento-utilizando-el-diseno-automatico-de-las-limitaciones-en-la-xcode-6)

Apenas estoy aprendiendo ios , espero le sirva hacen un ejemplo con un 4s y un 6 (orientaciones vertical y horizontal).